# I have a 1999 Isuzu Trooper. Can't figure out problems

Tags: automatic-transmission, isuzu

[image] 
I have a 1999 Isuzu Trooper. 3.5 liter V6. Automatic. My problem is, if I have it in neutral or park, the engine runs great. Smooth, no weird noises, it'll rev up to red line RPMs no problem. However as soon as I put it in drive it loses power. It'll barely drive, won't go over like 1500 RPMs. If I put it in 4 low it will act like it has more power and it will drive better. So I assume the problem is somewhere in the tranny/transfer case/torque converter. Or am I completely wrong? I'm no mechanic.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I don't think it would have to do with the transmission, but it might. There are some conditions which don't want to allow your engine to "go" when it's in gear, but work fine when not (or seem to). Usually if it's going to be a transmission issue, it would slip, not bind, meaning your engine would go sky high, but your Trooper wouldn't move anywhere. It could be something downstream of your transmission, such as your transfer (doubtful) or a differential. It might also be a dragging brake. It would have to be a serious brake dragging issue, but it is possible, especially the e-brake.

Comment: So if it's probably not those things. And if it wasn't the brake. Would you say it's the engine?

Comment: Probably not the engine itself, but might be some of the control systems (throttle body or what have you). Since it runs well in neutral/park, I'm thinking the engine itself is probably okay (so long as there's no weird noise).

Comment: No noise. It sounds great.

Comment: If you apply the brakes while in park does your engine RPM change?